# Создание функции из строки и контекст функции

Tags: javascript

Подскажите с вопросом:
Есть объект и строка из которой нужно создать функцию в контексте объекта.

```
const scope = {
  item : 1,
  array : [1,2,3]
}

const code = 'array.indexOf(item);'

const func = new Function(`return ${code}`);

func.call(scope); //??????????
```

Какой подход применить к такой задаче(eval() применять нельзя)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае, вы не обращаетесь к контексту. Есть специальное слово `this`, которое является ссылкой на текущий контекст

```js
const scope = {
  item : 1,
  array : [1,2,3]
}

// обращаемся к св-вам через this
const code = 'this.array.indexOf(this.item);'
const func = new Function(`return ${code}`);

console.log(func.call(scope));
```

Еще один вариант:  передавать данные в качестве параметров

```js
const scope = {
  array : [1,2,3],
  item : 1,
}


const code = 'array.indexOf(item);'
const func = new Function(...Object.keys(scope), `return ${code}`);

// но есть одна проблема. Нет ни какого стандарта на порядок ключей в объекте
// поэтому при вызове Object.keys в разных движках может быть разный порядок
// что не гарантирует, что скрипт будет работать всегда правильно
console.log(func(scope.array, scope.item));
```

Comment: Строка дана изначально в таком виде 'array.indexOf(item);' и для того, чтобы добавить this необходимо найти в этой строке свойства объекта.
Есть ли еще какие либо варианты?

Comment: стоп, вы не можете руками строку поменять?

Comment: В этом и суть, что ни 'this.' ни 'scope.' там не должно быть.

Comment: @Doigrales обновил ответ

Comment: Второй вариант вполне устраивает, но могу ли я создать функцию, указав в качестве параметров все ключи объекта(сейчас там всего два свойства, а может быть намного больше)?

Comment: @Doigrales еще раз обновил

Answer (score 0):

Просто можно менять scope и будет меняться код функции.

```js
const scope = {
  item : 1,
  array : [1,2,3],
  cat : 228,
  dog : 'Test',
  obj : { a: 1 },
  zero : 0,
  item1337 : 1337,
}
const code = 'array.indexOf(item)'
const func = generate(code, scope)

console.log(func())

function generate (code, scope) {
  const arg = Object.keys(scope)
  const argValues = JSON.stringify(Object.values(scope))
  const fullCode = `return ((${arg}) =>
    ${code} 
  )(...${argValues})`
  
  console.log(fullCode)
  
  return new Function(fullCode)
}
```